# Cloudformation hanging when calling resource "MyPhone223546421"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I need to create a dynamo db table with some attribute values using a Cloudformation template as follows:

```
PhoneNumber     |       OrderNumber

223546421               11545154
784578745               11547854
223458784               11547487
XXXXXXXXX               11578451
```

Were "XXXXXXXXX" is passed as a parameter.

Cloudformation template:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {
        "OrdersTable": {
            "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "Properties": {
                "TableName": "ClientOrders",
                "AttributeDefinitions": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "PhoneNumber",
                        "AttributeType": "S"
                    },
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "OrderNumber",
                        "AttributeType": "S"
                    }
                ],
                "KeySchema": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "PhoneNumber",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    },
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "OrderNumber",
                        "KeyType": "RANGE"
                    }
                ],
                "TimeToLiveSpecification": {
                    "AttributeName": "ExpirationTime",
                    "Enabled": true
                },
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": "10",
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": "5"
                }
            },
            "DependsOn": [
                "DynamoDBQueryPolicy"
            ]
        },
        "DynamoDBQueryPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyName": "DynamoDBQueryPolicy",
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": "dynamodb:Query",
                            "Resource": "*"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Roles": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "OrdersTableQueryRole"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "OrdersTableQueryRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": [
                                    "dynamodb.amazonaws.com"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Action": [
                                "sts:AssumeRole"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Path": "/"
            }
        },
        "MyPhone223546421": {
            "Type": "Custom::CrtUpdDltDynamodbDocumentLambda",
            "Properties": {
                "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:accountid:function:cfn-crt-upd-dlt-dynamodb-document",
                "DynamoTableName": "ClientOrders",
                "DynamoKeyProperty": "PhoneNumber",
                "DynamoItem": "{\n  \"PhoneNumber\": \"223546421\",\n  \"OrderNumber\": \"11545154\",\n  \"someKey\": \"someValue\"\n}\n"
            }
        },
        "MyPhone784578745": {
            "Type": "Custom::CrtUpdDltDynamodbDocumentLambda",
            "Properties": {
                "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:accountid:function:cfn-crt-upd-dlt-dynamodb-document",
                "DynamoTableName": "ClientOrders",
                "DynamoKeyProperty": "PhoneNumber",
                "DynamoItem": "{\n  \"PhoneNumber\": \"784578745\",\n  \"OrderNumber\": \"11547854\",\n  \"someKey\": \"someValue\"\n}\n"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It hangs when calling the lambda, of course this needs proper edition but im lacking skills to properly set it. This is the CF template for the lambda:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
    DynamoCfnLambdaRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                    - Effect: Allow
                      Principal:
                          Service:
                              - lambda.amazonaws.com
                      Action:
                          - sts:AssumeRole
            Path: '/'
            Policies:
                - PolicyName: dynamodbAccessRole
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: '2012-10-17'
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                - dynamodb:*
                            Resource: '*'
                          - Effect: Allow
                            Action:
                                - logs:*
                            Resource: '*'
    CfnCrtUpdDltDynamodbDocumentLambda:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
        Properties:
            FunctionName: 'cfn-crt-upd-dlt-dynamodb-document'
            Code:
                ZipFile: >
                    const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
                    const response = require("./cfn-response");
                    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
                    exports.handler = function(event, context) {
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
                      var item = JSON.parse(event.ResourceProperties.DynamoItem);
                      var keyProperty = event.ResourceProperties.DynamoKeyProperty;
                      var tableName = event.ResourceProperties.DynamoTableName;
                      if (event.RequestType == "Create" || event.RequestType == "Update") {
                        console.log("item:", item);
                        var params = {
                          TableName: tableName,
                          Item: item
                        };
                        console.log("Creating or Updating Document");
                        docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {                
                          if (err) {
                            console.log('error creating/updating document', err);
                            response.send(event, context, "FAILED", {}, tableName + '_' + item[keyProperty]);
                          } else {
                            response.send(event, context, "SUCCESS", {}, tableName + '_' + item[keyProperty]);
                          }
                        });
                      }

                      if (event.RequestType == "Delete") {
                        console.log("Deleting a Document");
                        var params = {
                          TableName: tableName,
                          Key: {
                            [keyProperty]: item[keyProperty]
                          }
                        };
                        docClient.delete(params, function(err, data) {
                          if (err) {
                            response.send(event, context, "FAILED", {});
                          } else {
                            response.send(event, context, "SUCCESS", {});
                          }
                        });
                      }
                    };
            Handler: index.handler
            Role: !GetAtt DynamoCfnLambdaRole.Arn
            Runtime: nodejs10.x
            Timeout: 60
```

Would really appreciate some detailed explanation if someone has the time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any errors in lambda logs in cloudwatch?

Comment: Can you confirm that lambda is being called?

Comment: Hi @BaluVyamajala, thanks for the help again. The lambda implicit on the CF body that you shared with me you said needed some variables replacement, im stuck at that point. Db get's created but attribute values aren't inserted. I know for sure that the lambda isn't correct, but im lacking skills for that piece of code to properly set it in conjunction with the main cf.

Comment: The only difference as i started in other , this custom resource is for only partition key, but your dynamo table has both partition and sort key. i can suggest some changes as an answer, but can't test it.

Comment: Please if you have time, take a look at the CF template. I believe i need to edit the variables from this part of the code "  ZipFile: > " until the end. item,keyproperty and tablename. The lambda stalls trying to look after that if im not mistaken and the CF process crashes until timeout.